# Using Dates in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to write a script to to delete values based on a date.

The code allows me to delete a row in the 3rd column if it is equal to a whole number or word. However I'm trying to get it to work with dates. The values in the 3rd column are dates and if it matches with the date in the script then it will be deleted. The date in the script should be yesterdays, I thought it was possible to use `new Date()-1`, but that doesn't seam to work.

Below is my working code:

```
 function readRows() { 
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
   var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
   var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
   var values = rows.getValues(); 

   var date = new Date();
   var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");

   var rowsDeleted = 0; 
   for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
   var row = values[i]; 
   if (row[3] == curDate) { 
   sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted); rowsDeleted++; } } };
```

I am trying to 1, make the dates work - I think this is due to an Integer thing.
And 2 get yesterdays date!

Thanks!

Comment: Your `curDate `  is not a date, it's a string that looks like a date. Does you spreadsheet contain dates or strings?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to start from the bottom when deleting rows.

```
function readRows() 
{ 
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
   var range = sheet.getDataRange(); 
   var numRows = range.getNumRows();
   var values = range.getValues();
   var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
   var rowsToDelete = []; 
   for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) 
   { 
     var row = values[i]; 
     if (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[3]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy") == curDate); 
     { 
       rowsToDelete.push(i);
     } 
   } 
   if(rowsToDelete.length)
   {
     for(var i=values.length-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
       if(rowsToDelete.indexOf(i)>-1)
       {
         sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
       }
     }
   }
}
```